# What is the purpose of both 802.11 re-authentication and re-association while roaming?

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, 802.11

I mean this. Firstly I've connected to my iPhone to my D-Link router :

[image: iphone to D-link authentication, association, eapol handshake]

And then I've moved to another floor and was reasonably connected to my another ZyXEL router that was closer:

[image: iphone to ZyXEL authentication, association, eapol handshake]

Authentication frames are always type 0 (open auth) nowadays and Association ones consist of information about NIC of the STA, but while **roaming** process in all of the types of security (Open, WEP, WPA2) there is exchange with authentication frames and reassociation frames between STA and AP.

**So my questions are:**

1. Why have not IEEE included information, that is contained in Association frame, into the Authentication frame? There wouldn't have been a necessity in Association frame exchange and thus roaming would have been faster a little.
2. The **disassociation** frames exist. Okay, I understand: the STA must notify the AP with message "good bye, I'm moving to another girl". But what is the purpose of **RE-authentication** frames then?

Comment: Note, AFAIK, WPA actually uses the "Open" authentication type and speaks EAPOL separately from that. The only other type, "Shared-key", seems to be a relic from WEP days.

Comment: @grawity Thank's for the comment. I decided to rename the question.
Yes, I know, that historically there were authentication frames for there direct purpose, but they have not manage that. But I can not understand what is the purpose now of both authentication and association frames, especially while roaming?

Comment: Why are you asking about "RE-authentication" frames? No such frame type exists. Did you mean to write "reassociation"?

Comment: @Spiff I know. I've meant not the type of frames exactly, but the processes, that occur while roaming. And in case of reassociation the designations have coincided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [IEEE Std 802.11-2012, 4.5.3.4 Reassociation](http://standards.ieee.org/about/get/802/802.11.html)

> Association is sufficient for no-transition message delivery between IEEE 802.11 STAs. Additional functionality is needed to support BSS-transition mobility and is provided by the reassociation service.
>
> The reassociation service is invoked to “move” a current association from one AP to another. This keeps the
> Distribution System informed of the current mapping between AP and STA as the STA moves from BSS to BSS within an
> ESS. Reassociation also enables changing association attributes of an established association while the STA
> remains associated with the same AP. Reassociation is always initiated by the mobile STA.

AP = Access point

STA = Station

BSS = Basic Service Set (basically the WiFi network constituted by one AP)

ESS = Extended Service Set (a WiFi network made of several APs)

*The abbreviations are given for long-term answer purposes.*

Comment: Thank's! Not the full answer as I've expected, but pretty enough. But I can not understand why STAs and APs still waste their time for re-authentication packets exchange as it's not necessary. I can only suppose that's only for the legacy purposes.